# Background Tint of a button is showing only on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, emulation, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to change the `backgroundTint` of a `button` in `android`.

When I change it I see it on `Android Studio`, but when I open the `emulator`(4.4) the `backgroundTint` is not showing .

But when I change the `background` its show normally on the `emulator`.

Also, some `button` showing in a different size than the `Android Studio` is showing

I figure out that the backgroundTint is only accepted on android 5.1.1 not even on 5.0 , how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the minimum version you want to support really is 4.4, then as you already discovered, BackgroundTint is not applicable. You need to use a drawable resource for this. If you want the button to change based on the state of the button, use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
android:dither=["true" | "false"]
android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
<item
    android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
    android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
    android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

Otherwise, you can just something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="@android:color/white" />
   <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />
</shape>
```

You'll put this under the res/drawable folder and reference it like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/whateveryounamedyourdrawable"
```